# Parametrized derived types with type-bound procedures

Tags: fortran, gfortran, derived-types

I manage to compile type-bound procedures of non-parametrized derived types, as well as parametrized types without bound procedures, but not parametrized derived types with bound procedures, using `gfortran-9`. Am I getting something wrong in the example below?

`simple.f90`:

```
module types
    implicit none
    type stype(s)
        integer, LEN :: s = 3
    contains
        procedure :: p=>print
    end type stype
contains
subroutine print(q)
    class(stype(*)), intent(in) :: q
    print*, q%s
end
end module

program p
    use types
    type(stype(5)) :: q
    call q%p
end program
```

`gfortran-9 simple.f90` gives:

```
simple.f90:6:17:

    6 |         procedure :: p=>print
      |                 1
Error: Argument ‘q’ of ‘print’ with PASS(q) at (1) must be of the derived-type ‘stype’
```

Comment: The code of the linked question may not be an exact match, but I think that the gcc bug is sufficiently close to say the issues are the same.  There are a few other related gcc bugs with type-bound procedures of parameterized types so the linked bug may not be the best fit, but we can say that your code is fine.

Comment: @francescalus Yes, it's even the exact same situation.

Comment: The solution I found was to update ubuntu to 20.04 which has `flang-7` in the `apt`-repos. It compiled smoothly with Flang.